# Calculate statistics on overlapping polygons with turf.js

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox, turf

In my Mapbox application, I have added draw tools to calculate the area of a polygon according to the [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/) provided in the documentation.

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: true
});

map.addControl(draw);

var calcButton = document.getElementById('calculate');
calcButton.onclick = function() {
    var data = draw.getAll();
    if (data.features.length > 0) {
        var area = turf.area(data);
        // restrict to area to 2 decimal points
        var rounded_area = Math.round(area*100)/100;
        var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
        answer.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + rounded_area/1000000 + '</strong></p><p>square km</p>';
    } else {
        alert("Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!");
    }
};
```

After adding a polygon layer (census tracts) from a geojson, my objective is to now calculate the sum of population in all of the census tracts that are *overlapped* by the drawn polygon - for example:

[image]

It is possible using `turf.js` to find out whether features overlap with `overlap(poly1, poly2)`, however according to the [documentation](https://github.com/tcql/turf-overlaps) this seems to only be possible only with  **turf polygons** as opposed to geojson polygons added as layers using the standard Mapbox library.

how would one read in a geojson file to turf and convert it to a multipolygon (with `turf.multiPolygon()`?) and then get specific properties (such as `Pop2010`) from those features that are overlapping?

The code below adds `censusTracts`, but how to get this layer to interact with turf.js?

```
map.addSource('censusTracts', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': 'wgs84.geojson'
});

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'density',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'censusTracts',
            "paint": {
              "fill-color" : {

                "property": "Pop2010",
                "stops": [
                    [1, "#FFFFFF"],
                    [82200, "#404040"]
                ]
            },
            'fill-opacity': 0.9,
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
          }

        });
```